# Choose all columns from the table with types int and varchar

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table stored at the testdb (database) and I need to choose all the columns of int and varchar types from it. I know about function mysql_field_type but it doesn't work in the 5th version of php.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$host = '127.0.0.1';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';

$link = mysqli_connect($host , $user, $passw , 'testdb');

if(!$link){
    echo "Connection failure";
}else{
    echo "Connection success!";
}

$result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM `test_table`');

 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
    $table[] = $row; 
}
print_r ($table);

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try running a query of the form:

```
select column_name
from Information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'test_table' and (data_type = 'int' or data_type = 'varchar');
```

This should return you a list of all columns in test_table that are of int or varchar. You can then iterate over them, and pull out the values for them either by query concatenation in PHP, or on a foreach.

Answer (score 2):

You can use fetch_field for this. (https://www.php.net/manual/tr/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php)

```
$cols = array();

while($field = $result->fetch_field()){
    if($field->type == 3 || $field->type == 253){
        $cols[] = $field->name;
    }
}
print_r($cols);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already storing your value in $table array try this on any column

if you want to select column name then your query should be like this

select column_name from Table_name

Use `is_numeric function`

```
foreach ($table as $new_array)
{
    if(is_numeric($new_array))
    {
        $number[]=$new_array;
    }
    else{
        $string[]=$new_array;
    }
}

print_r($string);//see the result
print_r($number);//see the result
```

Check this link:-http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php